# If a View Controller tries to get rid of it's view, what happens with the superview?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

Think of this: A view controller's view is added as subview to another view. Now the view controller tries to unload that due to low-memory warning. I believe that is impossible because it is retained by the superview. But what if the VC really unloads the view, and then loads it back again when it is needed? Who will add is as subview to the superview? Doesn't make a lot of sense to me. So I guess the unloading of the view will not happen when the view of the view controller is still a subview of a superview...

Comment: interesting! can you edit the question and put the scenario as a list with bullets. will help others to glance quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right. The view controller won't unload its view if the view currently has a superview. That behavior mostly affects view controllers that've gone offscreen, e.g. in a navigation controller.